# angular ng-repeat without controller

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angular and would like to understand why the list li in mainMenu.html is showing the data from the json file even thou there is **no controller in the mainMenu.html**

And if MainMenuCtrl is the controller as indicated in app.js, How can I implement `ng-click="tappedMenu(item)` inside the li tag as well? Thanks

```js
//---app.js-----------------------------------------

(function () {                                          
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('angApp', ['ngRoute'])                  
        .config(['$routeProvider', routeProvider]);    
})();

function routeProvider ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/list', {
        templateUrl: 'views/mainMenu.html',
        controller: 'MainMenuCtrl'
    }).otherwise({      //home page
        redirectTo: '/list'
    });
}


angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['angApp']);
});


//---controllers.js-----------------------------------------

angular
    .module('angApp')                                                   
    .controller('MainMenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', MainMenuCtrl]);    

function MainMenuCtrl ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('js/mainMenu.json').then(
        function (response) {
            $scope.menuItems = response.data;
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("http error");
        }
    )
}
```

```html
//---index.html-----------------------------------------

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/headerCtrl.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body>

<main ng-view></main>


</body>
</html>


//---mainMenu.html-----------------------------------------

<section class="mainMenu">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in menuItems" ng-click="tappedMenu(item)">
            <image src="images/{{item.image}}_.png"></image>
            {{item.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: if you wanted to bind something on UI or it should be there inside `scope/rootScope` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller is defined in your app.js, is `MainMenuCtrl`.
For the second question you need to implement a function in the same controller called `tappedMenu` that takes as parameter an item. You have to write something like :

```
function MainMenuCtrl ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('js/mainMenu.json').then(
        function (response) {
            $scope.menuItems = response.data;
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("http error");
        }
    )

    $scope.tappedMenu = function(item) {
        /*do whatever you want with the clicked item*/
    }
}
```

So if you define a controller with $routeProvider you don't have to define it explicitly also in the view (html file).

Comment: in the function you suggested. How does $scope know about its argument "item"?

Comment: you can call that argument whatever you want `function(clickedItem)` is good too, the name doesn't matter, but this argument is the same you pass from the view `tappedMenu(item)` where item is the single element from array menuItems which is linked to controller with $scope.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the router is responsible for attaching the controller to your template:

```
function routeProvider ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/list', {
    templateUrl: 'views/mainMenu.html',
    controller: 'MainMenuCtrl'
  }).otherwise({      //home page
    redirectTo: '/list'
  });
}
```

The `/list` route is bound to `mainMenu.html` with controller `MainMenuCtrl`.
([See official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute#!))

As for your second question, just add any method you need in the controller, as Popescu has already shown:

```
$scope.whatever = function(){...}
```

And in the template:

```
<li ng-click="whatever()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write 'tappedMenu' function inside 'MainMenuCtrl'.
Otherwise everything is ok.
If you face any problem then knock me.